# How many bit strings of length 7 exist if the string remains unchanged if it is reversed?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, string-theory

How many bit strings of length 7 exist if the string remains unchanged if it is reversed ?

1 1 1 1 1 1 1 and 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 are an example that is unchanged if reversed.

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 and 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 would then also be unchanged..

Is there some way to calculate this? or do I have to find all the 128 bit strings and reverse them to see if they fit?

Comment: How many bit strings of length $4$ are there? What do you get if you take a 4-bit string $abcd$ and reflect it about the fourth bit to make $abcdcba$?

Comment: of length 4, 4 exist 1 1 1 1, 0 0 0 0, 1 0 0 1 and 0 1 1 0.

Comment: I didn't mean how many _symmetric_ 4-bit strings, I meant how may 4-bit strings in total. (I was hoping you could figure it out for yourself from there, but Doug Spoonwood has done it for you.)

Comment: total 4 bit strings are 4^2

Comment: No. it is not $4^2$. well yes, it is $4^2$, but only because $4^2=2^4$.

Comment: @looooost, you have $4$ digits, for each digit you have $2$ options, either on, or off. so for the first digit you have 2 options, for the second 2 options, for the third 2 options, for the fourth 2 options, thats $2*2*2*2=2^4=16$. your answer (4^2) is correct only by coincidence.

Comment: yeah sorry I meant 2^4, just typo :(, thank you

Answer (score 1):

So consider a string

1. a b c d e f g.

If we reverse this string we have

2. g f e d c b a.

Now by hypothesis the first digit of 1. corresponds to the first digit of 2, the second digit of 1. to the second digit of 2 as follows:

```
a b c d e f g
| | | | | | |
g f e d c b a
```

Thus, if and only if a bit string remains the same when reversed, then and only then a=g, b=f, and c=e.  So, if we figure out how many bit strings of length 4 exist, we'll have figured out the answer.  And more generally, if we have a bit strength of length x, then:

The number of palindromic bit strings of length x is equal to the number of bit strings of length

x/2 if x is even,

or the number of bit strings of length (x+1)/2 if x is odd.

Comment: You mean $(x+1)/2$, not $(x-1)/2$.